# При сравнении 2 одинаковых массивов получается false

Tags: javascript

Почему 2 одинаковых массива не равны?

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(a == b); //false
```

Comment: `a.every( e => b.includes(e) )`

Answer (score 3):

### Почему 2 одинаковых массива не равны?

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Операторы_сравнения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> Сравнение объекта истинно лишь в том случае, если оба операнда ссылаются на один и тот же объект в памяти

### как сравнить ?

**Обновлено**, спасибо ( Suvitruf ) за замечание
для сравнения массивов (НЕ)достаточно привести к строке

```
console.log(a.toString() == '' + b); // true
[ 1, 2 ].toString() == [ '1,2' ].toString() // true
```

для сравнения объектов можно воспользоваться этим способом

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  a: 'A'
}) == JSON.stringify({
  a: 'A'
})); // true

console.log(JSON.stringify([ 1, 2 ]) == JSON.stringify([ '1, 2' ])); // false
```

---

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(a.toString() == '' + b); // true

console.log([1, 2].toString() == ['1,2'].toString()) // true 

console.log(JSON.stringify({
  a: 'A'
}) == JSON.stringify({
  a: 'A'
})); // true

console.log(JSON.stringify([1, 2]) == JSON.stringify(['1, 2'])); // false
```

Comment: `toString() ` - совсем...`[ 1, 2 ].toString() == [ '1,2' ].toString() // true`, что, как бы, не верно.

Comment: аргумент, благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Вы сравниваете ссылки. Для сравнения значений, нужно сравнивать элементы.

В ES6 можно так:

```
a.every( e => b.includes(e) );
```

С помощью [underscorejs](https://underscorejs.org/) можно так:

```
_.isEqual(a, b);
```

Comment: Первый вариант не только работает за квадрат, но и не проверяет порядок элементов. То ли дело старый-добрый `for`...

Comment: @Regent это ж как пример. Мой главным посыл лишь в том, что сравнивать нужно не по ссылке. Если там внутри одни int'ы, то можно и самим в цикле прогонять.

Comment: Посыл понятен, но ведь [такой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2xb093yk/1/) - это, согласитесь, не дело

Comment: @Regent ответ стараюсь давать как можно более общий, чтоб не только топи стартеру ответить, но и тем, кто в будущем прочитает вопрос-ответ. Конкретная реализация зависит от элементов. Если там один уровень вложенности, то можно в цикле прогнать, если там комплексные элементы, то уже надо думать.